# Calculated Column Incorrect when All Day Event is selected

Tags: calendar, calculated-column, date-time, bug

I've created a Calendar list.  I've added a single calculated column ("Calculated Start Time") that simply references the "Start Time" column.  It reports the correct date when the event is not an all day event.  When I create an All Day Event, however, the calculated column reports 5 hours previous (i.e. 7pm the previous day).

It looks like when there is an All Day Event, the math for the calculated column is assuming the Start Date is in UTC or something (I am in Eastern Standard Time == 5 hour difference between UTC).

It looks like someone else has seen this behavior too: http://weblogs.asp.net/zekemouseover/archive/2010/05/11/start-time-amp-calculated-column-wonkiness-in-a-sharepoint-event-calendar.aspx

Is this a known thing?  Is it documented?  Is it scheduled for fix?

TIA

Comment: Is the time zone set properly for your Site?

Comment: This is an issue regardless of the time zone settings.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in the October 2012 CU pack.  We had the same issue and the Oct CU fixed it.

Comment: I'll attempt to confirm this when I have some time to snapshot and apply the hotfix.

Comment: I applied the December 2012 CU, and this doesn't appear to be fixed (or maybe it has regressed again)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula in the Start Date calculation:

=TEXT(IF([End Time]=[Start Time],[Start Time],IF(MOD(ROUNDUP(([End Time]-[Start Time])*24,0),24)=0,[Start Time]+1,[Start Time])),"dd mmm yyyy")